# Word to describe someone who publishes many works?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes an author who publishes many works?

"Profuse" comes to mind, but this word has a broader meaning.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think 'prolific' is a decent choice here.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prolific):

> 2. producing in large quantities or with great frequency; highly productive:
>      *a prolific writer.*

Answer (score 3):

**intellectually productive or fecund** come to mind though I find "prolific" (already mentioned in an answer) a better choice.

> - **"productive"** -  [**MW**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/productive) - Marked by abundant production or achievement: a productive career.
> - **"fecund"** -   [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fecund) -  Characterized by intellectual productivity: a fecund mind.

Comment: 'Prolific' or 'productive' are both good, 'fecund' is not used in daily English.

Answer (score 2):

Prodigious was the term I was struggling to remember, even though prolific was first to pop into my mind.

Prodigious is more apropos than ‘prolific’ when emphasizing remarkable.

> pro·di·gious adjective: prodigious
>
> ```
> 1.
> remarkably or impressively great in extent, size, or degree.
> "the stove consumed a prodigious amount of fuel"
> ```

Comment: Hello, Shelby. A prodigious author? It _is_ used, but seems nowhere near as idiomatic as a _prolific author_ (raw Google results, and [Google 2-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+prodigious+author%2Cprolific+author&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I reiterate and further clarify that the etymology [suggests](https://www.etymonline.com/word/prodigious) that _prodigious_ is for emphasizing a higher-level (quality, quantity, frequency, clairvoyance) of output than just the [flowering fecundity](https://www.etymonline.com/word/prolific) of _prolific_. I was struggling to think of a less blasé adjective that would place more emphasis on exceptionalism, not just atypical grunt. Mark Twain wasn’t just a prolific “Dear Abby” Abigail Van Buren.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hello Edwin. A motivation is I thought it might help others who were looking for an alternative to _prolific_ which is not easily found being not listed as a synonym in the renown online dictionaries’ thesauruses, only on the [Great in number](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/prolific.html#C0-6) category of WordHippo. Standard synonyms seem solely focused on abundant production. Prodigious is unique in that it has come to mean colossal but historically also means exceptional, abnormal, monstrous or freakish, maybe even reckless abandon as in _prodigal_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth from our prior run-ins, have you noted I am ENTP and you’re ostensibly not— probably IS__. I place a high value on ideas. My personality type is highly creative and visionary. Apologies if this conflicts with your interpretation of the best, canonical or intended use of this site. I’m just trying to use it to help myself and others. Hopefully not corrupting it with improper English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “Lies, damned lies, and statistics.” My steelman rebuttal is to rerun your data query on all phases in contexts intended to emphasize the extraordinary, abnormal. I would grant a rebuttal that this question didn’t ask for such qualifiers exceptional than ‘many’. Yet I think I am allowed to answer the question pointing out a word that both answers the question for those who also might be looking for additional qualification, notwithstanding non-qualified relative usage. Is this site intended to reduce our vocabulary?

Comment: '_Prodigious_ is unique in that it has come to mean colossal but historically also means exceptional, abnormal, monstrous or freakish, maybe even reckless abandon as in prodigal.'  None of the above seem to relate well to 'prolific [in output]'. However, as CD contains 'She was a prodigious musician', I'll not downvote, though I see [these Google 3-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+prodigious+author%2Ca+prolific+author&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) as a more realistic guide to idiomaticity (and ELU concentrates on standard usages). And when ...

Comment: it comes to being helpful, 'helping people sound reasonably natural' is an important consideration ... and note that OP includes '"Profuse" comes to mind, but this word **has a broader meaning**', showing a desire for a prototypical rather than peripheral usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth MWD defines, _“extraordinary in bulk, quantity, or degree; resembling or befitting a prodigy.”_ A synonym is _vast_. How does a prodigious author refer to anything other than the vastness and/or other freakishly exceptional facet of output? The ginormous size of the author’s head or chosen font is blatantly inane. Given the definition of the [etymologically unrelated](https://archive.ph/wip/qRp6i) prodigal, _“giving something on a lavish scale”_, we have [“or the prodigal gifts of an artist.”](https://www.simonsaysai.com/blog/the-continuing-evolution-of-prodigious-4611b4f086ef)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The definition of _profuse_ includes “exuberantly plentiful, lavish.” Which implies the question was asking to qualify the _many_ as exceptionally or lavishly many. The question does not state, _“What word **only** describes an author who publishes many works **and does not attempt to qualify the exceptional or remarkable degree of the quantity**?”_ I actually found this page because I was searching for a word to express that an author has been exceptionally productive. Thus Google thinks this page is trying to answer such query. Extant answers didn’t suffice so I had to think.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’ll steelman your digrams data point again. Google’s chart lacks vertical axis log-scaling, thus proportional change is not accurately depicted btwn smaller & larger values. Disingenuously depicts _prolific author_ outpacing _prodigious author_ [since 1970](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prodigious+author%2Cprolific+author&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019), but actually the opposite! And [markedly so](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prodigious+writing%2Cprolific+writing&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019) in recent years.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’m referencing here American English statistics because ostensibly this site is vastly more visited by Americans than Brits. I see nearly no British English on this site. _Prolific_ is more frequently used than _prodigious_, but not if [prefixed with _was_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+prodigious%2Cwas+prolific&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019). Thus your chosen digram as a presumptive proxy for use of the terms in the context of describing someone who produces many works may not be statistically accurate and representative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I highly resent the implication that my effort was not a virtuous and valid attempt to help. And frankly this crap has to end. I must redouble my efforts replace all these centralized websites with decentralized replacements on a blockchain w\my longstanding idea for decentralized curation. How to waste several hours on what should have been the original minute to share, just because someone thinks someone else is wrong on the Internet. And ye wonder why all the centralized mass media are dying. Soon this site to die also.